# .js scope program throwing error

Tags: javascript, console.log

I've looked into it and cannot figure out why this program is throwing an error in the console.

```js
var laundryRoom = 'Basement';
var mailRoom = 'Room 1A';

function myApartment() {
  var mailBoxNumber = 'Box 3';
  var laundryRoom = 'In-unit';
  console.log('Mail box: ' + mailBoxNumber + ', Laundry:' + laundryRoom);
}

console.log('Laundry: ' + laundryRoom + ', Mail: ' + mailRoom);
console.log(myApartment());
```

Output:

```
Laundry: Basement, Mail: Room 1A
Mail box: Box 3, Laundry:In-unit
undefined
```

Everything seems fine until this last "undefined".

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to print the result returned by the function, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: **myApartment is a function**

The return value of a function is undefined.

Please put a return in your function.

Comment: It doesn't throw any error!?

Answer (score 1):

`myApartment()` doesn't `return` anything explicitly, so it implicitly returns `undefined`. Just call `myApartment()` directly, not `console.log(myApartment());`.

Answer (score 0):

**myApartment is a function**

The return value of a function is undefined.

Please put a return in your function.